# Adding soft delete to Identity users table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I've added a deleted at column to my Users table but obviously registering new users method provided by Identity framework still sees these users in the database, is there a way of telling it to ignore a certain column?

**Registration**

```
// this needs to ignore any DeletedAt where not null
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    ...
}
```

**Logging in**

```
// this needs to ignore any DeletedAt where not null
result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync( user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true );
```

...And any other external login things going on need to be told about the column.

Comment: For login: you want to check if user "is deleted" and not let him log in? About registration what is the probleme?

Comment: Just inherit from `SignInManager` and add check for `IsDeleted`

Comment: tmg - I don't want the login methods allowing deleted users to login... / Thanks trailmax

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `signInManager` overwrite the `SignInAsync` method, this one is used in every login proccess (local or external)

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<User, int>
{    

     public override async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
     {
         if (!user.isDeleted)
         {
             await base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
         } 
         else
         {
             ...
         }                      
     }
}
```

Or create a custom `UserStore` and override `GetUserAggregateAsync` method (its called inside all "find" methods):

```
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }

    protected override async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression<Func<ApplicationUser, bool>> filter)
    {
        var user = await base.GetUserAggregateAsync(filter);

        // if user is found but soft deleted then ignore and return null
        if (user != null && user.IsDeleted)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, how would you handle the [else] in this case? I'm assuming that I need to return back a [SignInStatus] model with value [Failure] to make it look like the user doesn't exist but theres no return parameter to use. What would you have to do to make it so it returns a failure so it's visible on the screen (i.e. for login, say check your details and try again because the login doesn't exist)

Comment: @Hanho You are right, you can not return a `SignInStatus`. You can try create custom `UserStore` and filter out the `IsDeleted` users, so that `UserManager` methods with return "failure" when try to retrieve the user

Comment: I've been trying to do what you've suggested for the past month and i still cannot figure out where to place this. I've tried to override the user object in a custom user store (only to find out I cannot filter it using linq and placing it back into an IDBSet - safely casting it to IDBSet returns a null). Same thing in the ApplicationDbContext. I tried in the FindByIdAsync method by checking if a user is deleted there and returning a 0 (which kind of works) but if you return 0, it returns an exception - not what i would have expected. Any idea on where I can proceed? Thanks

Comment: great, thanks for your help tmg, this appears to be what i need. When trying to login with a IsDeleted item, it successfully recognises that it's been deleted and stops login. However i have found that if you try to register for a new user using the same email address as one thats been deleted, it throws an error which im guessing is due to the way that the identities are handled (not allowing duplicates of the email addresses). Any idea how I can override this so it only checks for the ID for primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `Users` property in the base UserStore and register it as `IUserStore<ApplicationUser>`

```cs
public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser,...>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public override IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Users => base.Users.Where(u => !u.Deleted);
}
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
```