# How to use ApplicationUser soft delete with IsDelete property in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

We are using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity v1.0.0.0 in our project. We have to delete our application users softly (only make them `IsDeleted =true`), not permanently from database.

Everything works with this, but when we want to create new user with same Username it's checking the `IsDeleted` one also. We want that in this case it will not check the `IsDeleted` user.

Is there any way to override the `public virtual Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync` function for this scenario?

Comment: Username is a unique index on the table in SQL. if you change CreateAsync to do not validate it, then you will get DbUpdateException

Comment: @tmg are you sure about that? in Identity v2 there is no unique index and username uniqueness is enforced in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free up the username for use by others, you can simply modify it when the user is deleted.

Make it something something unique, perhaps: `"{user}_deleted_{guid}"`. The user's email will still be in-tact and you can have multiple user entries with the same email so that's not a problem.

Also, it might be good to store a `DeletedDate` property instead of a `IsDeleted` property. It is functionally equivalent (just check if it is not null) but it also gives you some added information for free! Combine this with a `DeletedBy` column to track who did it.

Once you've done that, you can create a custom `UserStore` which will not return deleted users in results. You can read more on this over at this question [Adding soft delete to Identity users table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458914/adding-soft-delete-to-identity-users-table)